# Average Power and Instantaneous Power

Tags: power

I am confused between the usage of the terms average power and instantaneous power. What is the main difference between the two?

Comment: Do you know, more generally, how *averaged* quantities differ from *instantaneous* ones? That's all there is to it.

Comment: Yes i do know but somehow i am not able to relate with this particular case.

Comment: Average power is what you get if you average the power of some period of time. Usually, the power varies in some way that repeats itself over time. In that case, you only need to average over one single period.

Comment: You're asking about the difference between the slope of a secant and the slope of a tangent in mathematics.  Maybe this page will help:  http://clas.sa.ucsb.edu/staff/lee/secant,%20tangent,%20and%20derivatives.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of work  performed during "a period of time"

$\Rightarrow $ Average Power $= \frac{\Delta W}{\Delta t}$

for example, the work is  $W_1=3 \, \mathrm{ J} $ at time $t_1= 2\, \mathrm{ sec.}$ and   $W_2=7 \, \mathrm{ J} $ at time $t_2= 13\, \mathrm{ sec.}$

$\Rightarrow $ the duration is $\Delta t = t_2-t_1=13-2\, (\mathrm{ sec.}) $

$\Rightarrow $ the amount of work is $\Delta W = W_2-W_1=7-3\, (\mathrm{ J}) $

$\Rightarrow $ Average Power is $\frac{\Delta W}{\Delta t}=\frac{7-3}{13-2}=\frac{4}{11}\, (\mathrm{ J/s }) $

If the time interval $\Delta t \to 0 \Rightarrow \Delta t=dt, \Delta W=dW$

(It means that the Power is at some moment. )

$\Rightarrow $ Instantaneous Power $= \frac{d W}{d t}$

Answer (score 0):

"Instantaneous power". or "IPP" .would be the amount of power delivered or required for a VERY short time..but NOT for any "long period", such as that needed  by the starting motor..to crank an automobile engine.That "IPP" level may be VERY high..as much as 250-400 AMPS.. or maybe about 4 kilowatts..but ONLY for maybe 2-3 seconds and less on a warm engine. THEN.. the engine starts..and the  power required by the starting motor  drops to ZERO..So..in "watts", measured in "watt-hours', the TRUE consumed power is maybe 2 watts or LESS..since it takes 3600 seconds to produce 1 hour. So..if you need 300 amps but only for 3 SECONDS..then none.. the TOTAL "watt-hour" usage would be only a few watt/hours.

"Average power" on the other hand.. is power used over some TIME period, such as an hour or more. Take an A/C unit, say 10K btu or so.. If it is on constantly at high speed for one hour and draws "1100 watts", then the TOTAL consumed power would be 1.1KW/Hour.  The power is pretty much constant..throughout the whole time period of one hour..compared to starting an engine..where the power needed for a few seconds is huge, but then drops to zero, in a few seconds.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Try to format your answer so it reads like something that would go on print: no needless "all caps" and proper punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to be clear about **power** (measured in Watt or Joule/sec) and not confuse it with **energy** (measured in Watt-seconds or Joule Kg m^2 s^-2). Average power (over a time interval Δt=t2−t1) is the energy change in that time, E2−E1, where E may be work done, or energy used, or energy stored, etc. User219060 muddles power and energy, eg, watt-hour is NOT a power, and watt/hour is plain silly.

Instantaneous power is just taking Δt→0. To formally evaluate this needs a formula for Energy wrt time - E(t). Instantaneous power is a function of time. It may be measured "instantaneously", or from some assumptions, or by a variational methods derivation if an adequate description of the system is known.

T.